# Sending Strings Encoded by a secret key over TCP stream BadPaddingException with Windows

Tags: java, windows, tcp, encryption

I think I'm having a problem specific to the Windows operating system (windows 7) using the writeUTF() and readUTF() methods for sending encrypted strings over a TCP connection.

The client and server first establish a connection using a private-public key pair. Then they agree on a shared key that is used for further communications. The problem occurs when strings encrypted by the shared key and sent via writeUTF() and readUTF() have bad padding. The first instance when it occurs is when an encrypted acknowledgement from the server to the client using the writeUTF() method is sent.

The problem only occurs sometimes! Sometimes the program runs smoothly through to completion with no errors, however other times a BadPaddingException is thrown stating that the "Given final block not properly padded" at both Client side:

```
            byte[] byteDecriptedAck = decryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedAck.getBytes());
```

and Server side:

```
            byte[] byteDecriptedAck = decryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedPassword.getBytes());
```

The problem does NOT occur when running the code on OSX operating system. Therefore, I believe it has something to do with how windows represents UTF strings, writes UTF strings or reads UTF strings.

I'm at a loss for trying to fix this problem. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

The code for establishing connection client side:

```
private void establishConnection() {
    try {
        int numBytesPubKey = in.readInt();
        byte[] bytesPubKey = new byte[numBytesPubKey];
        in.readFully(bytesPubKey, 0, numBytesPubKey);

        //get public key from server
        X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytesPubKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

        //generate secret key for communicating
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(128); //key size
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
        byte[] encodedSecretKey = secretKey.getEncoded();

        //use public key to encode message containing secret key to send to server
        encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] cipherData = encryptCipher.doFinal(encodedSecretKey);

        //send secret key to server encoded by servers public key
        out.writeInt(cipherData.length);
        out.write(cipherData, 0, cipherData.length);

        //read acknowledge from server
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encodedSecretKey,"AES");

        String encryptedAck = in.readUTF();
        decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] byteDecriptedAck = decryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedAck.getBytes());

        if(!(new String(byteDecriptedAck).equals("ACK"))) {
            System.err.println("Server acknowledgement corrupted. Terminate communications.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //send password to server

        encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] cipheredPassword = encryptCipher.doFinal("password".getBytes());
        out.writeUTF(new String(cipheredPassword));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code for establishing connection server side:

```
private void establishConnection() {
    try {
        //generate public/private key pair for communicating with initially
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
        keyGen.initialize(1024, random);

        KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privKey = pair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey pubKey = pair.getPublic();

        //send public key to client
        byte[] bytesPubKey = pubKey.getEncoded();
        out.writeInt(bytesPubKey.length);
        out.write(bytesPubKey, 0, bytesPubKey.length);

        //read in secret key to use for further communications
        int numBytesSecretKey = in.readInt();
        byte[] bytesSecretKey = new byte[numBytesSecretKey];
        in.readFully(bytesSecretKey, 0, numBytesSecretKey);

        decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey, decryptCipher.getParameters());
        byte[] byteDecriptedSecretKey = decryptCipher.doFinal(bytesSecretKey);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(byteDecriptedSecretKey,"AES");

        //send back acknowledgment encoded with secret key: ACK
        encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] cipheredACK = encryptCipher.doFinal("ACK".getBytes());

        out.writeUTF(new String(cipheredACK));

        //read password from client
        String encryptedPassword = in.readUTF();
        decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] byteDecriptedAck = decryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedPassword.getBytes());

        if(!(new String(byteDecriptedAck).equals("password"))) {
            System.err.println("Access Denied. Client password incorrect. Terminate communications.");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Access Granted.");
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: "using the writeUTF() and readUTF() methods for sending encrypted strings" Then you're already making a mistake. `String` is not a container for binary data; and UTF is for `Strings,` not binary data, and that includes the 'modified UTF-8' format used by `writeUTF()` and `readUTF()`. You need to use `read(byte[])` and `write(byte[])`, possibly in conjunction with length-word prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] cipheredACK = encryptCipher.doFinal("ACK".getBytes());
out.writeUTF(new String(cipheredACK));
```

That's not going to work. UTF and String are for character data. You have raw bytes here, that cannot be interpreted as text.

Send them as binary data:

```
out.write(cipheredACK);
```

The reason that you see a difference between OS X and Windows is that you did not specify a character encoding when coercing your bytes into a String, so it becomes platform-specific. If this was really character data, you'd pass a character set to the constructor to make it platform-independent. But in your case, it is not character data anyway, so go with just the bytes.

Also, why don't you just use SSL?

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks a lot. I thought the Java Virtual machine automatically implemented SSL on top of the TCP layer?

Comment: If you think that, why do you still encrypt your packets? But no, the JVM does not "magically" switch on SSL. You have to ask for that. And when you do, you don't need to roll your own transport encryption.

Comment: My understanding of SSL is not what it should be... but I think I get it now. SSL does seem much simpler =)